# Issue in setting dynamic priority in sitemap php

Tags: php, mysql, sitemap, sitemap.xml

I am making a Dynamic sitemap, what I wanted is a priority that should be different. Suppose If the URL is new then the priority should be 0.6400 but if the URL is a two-month-old priority should be 0.5400. I have made this in the following way

HERE is the code. Please guide is it the right way and will not create issues in the future?
:-

```
<?php


header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");

echo '<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->'.PHP_EOL; 

echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">' . PHP_EOL;




while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result15)){
echo $row1['post_date'];
$Created_at= $row1['post_date'];
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d",$Created_at);
$Created_at= $d->format("Y-m");
    echo '<url>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<loc>'.'https://www.domain.in/post/'.$row1["id"].'/'. str_replace(' ','-',trim(preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;',$row1['slug']))).'</loc>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<lastmod>'.date('c',time()).'</lastmod>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>' . PHP_EOL;
           if($Created_at <= date('Y-m', strtotime(date('Y-m')." -2 month"))){
    echo "<priority>0.5400</priority>".PHP_EOL;
}  else{
    echo "<priority>0.6400</priority>".PHP_EOL;
}
    echo '</url>' . PHP_EOL;
  }

  echo '</urlset>' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: Does this code not work? Please show the output and explain what the problem is.

Comment: @ChrisHaas It is working ,  but I am beginner  so I want know this the right way and will not create problem in future?????